# Why Linux server closed the SSH client unexpectly and killed all the process started by the me?

Tags: ssh

I'm using a CentOS(`CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`) to upload data to cluster, the bandwidth reached to about 100MByte/s (and the net usage is full). Also, a redis(v=3.2.1) server (0.0.0.0:6379) running to maintain the uploading state. I run the redis-server at backend(not quit after SSH exited):

```
$ (redis-server redis.conf &)
```

By login the CentOS from another Linux (name jump-server), sometimes(not always happen, but often), the CentOS will close the SSH client:

```
Connection to <CentOS-ip> closed by remote host.
```

with `-vvv` option added for `ssh -vvv root@centos-ip`, I get more message when the connection closed by the server:

```
$ debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 11549
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
#0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r 4 w 5 e 6
Connection to <CentOS-ip> closed by remote host.
Connection to <CentOS-ip> closed.
Transferred: sent 8520, received 82248 bytes, in 474.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 18.0, received 173.5
debug1: Exit status -1
```

and the redis-server also gone! I `grep`ed the redis.log (DBEUG level), there is no error or crash hint. And I started a sleepy process on the server:

```
# sleep.py
import time
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)

# run as (python sleep.py &)
```

after SSH closed, the process gone too!

Why this happen? The messy truth is, *all the process I started gone!* why?

There may be a lot of reason lead this issue, please give me some hints, and I can supply other info to debug the issue if required. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Some TCP/IP Stacks in the middle of the route, like the hops in the middle , between your server and your endpoint client, actually cause the connection to be closed if keepalive is not used and connection keeping KeepAlive packets are not sent:::::
Try:::

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=15 -i ~/MYDIR/id_rsa    ec2-user(or--root)@myserver.com
```

Does that help you keep the connections??